# Ui-router states appending to existing ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

App structure

```
$stateProvider.
    state('azured', {
        url: "/azured/",
    }).
    state('azured.ref', {
        url: "/ref",
    }).
    state('azured.ref.table', {
        url: "/table/:tableId",
    }).
    state('azured.ref.table.list', {
        url: "/list/:listId",
    }).
    state('azured.ref.table.list.item', {
        url: "/item/:itemId",
    });
```

Each state's templates where made as widget.

```
<div container>
    <div header></div>
    <div body></div>
</div>
<ui-view  />
```

But i don't know how to append new states to current state. Say i have another states:

```
    .
    state('asd', {
        url: "/asd",
    }).
    state('asd.ref', {
        url: "/ref",
    });
```

When i navigate to `/asd` from `/` i see right state. But i want to navigate to this state from

```
/azured/ref/tableId/12/listId/3/itemId/434
```

and don't destroy current widgets but append 
(make url as `/azured/ref/tableId/12/listId/3/itemId/434/asd`)
 (please note *asd*). Just want to append new state to the current state and go on further. Guess i can hardcode all possible branches, but need better solution.

Here is preview
[image]

Comment: the other solution is you can use `$stateChangeStart` which has 5 arguments `event,toState,toParams,FromState,FromParams`.. what you can do is check from state and then redirect the way you want but you have to add regex to the `$stateProvider` state declaration in such a way that the regex satisfies the above url(without asd)

Comment: why would i regex it? why not leave it and append new url to that existing state? In fact i don't understand how it should be handled, someones says it's design issue, but how ms azure blade works then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into ui-router-extras. I'm on n'y phone. Don't have the URL but Google it